# Looping through OleDbDataReader .Read to produce delimited text file. Why does this code slow down as it loops?

Tags: oracle, vb.net, oledbdatareader

I have an VB.NET application that uses an Oracle OleDbDataReader to pull ~15 million rows from an Oracle database and write them to a | delimited text file.

```
Private Sub GenerateTextSqlReportWithCurrent(report As TblreportEntity, filename As String)

        Const batchSize = 20000

        Dim encryption As New ClassEncrypt

        'get data
        LogEvent($"INFO:          Opening DataReader for report {report.ReportName}")
        Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = IMOracle2.GetDataReader(report.Sql, IMOracle2.GetConnectString(My.Settings.DB_Instance, encryption.Decrypt(My.Settings.DB_UserID), encryption.Decrypt(My.Settings.DB_PWD)))
        LogEvent($"INFO: Finished Opening DataReader for report {report.ReportName}")
        
        LogEvent($"INFO: writing {report.ReportName} to {filename}")
        WriteToFile(filename, GetColumnTitlesHeader(reader), False)
        
        Dim batch As New StringBuilder()

        Dim lastReport As DateTime = DateTime.Now()
        Dim rowCount As Integer
        While reader.Read()
            For i = 0 To reader.FieldCount - 1
                Dim output As String
               '' output = Replace(reader(i).ToString, vbCr, "")
                output = Replace(reader.GetValue(i).ToString, vbCr, String.Empty)
                output = Replace(output, vbLf, String.Empty)
                output = Replace(output, "|", String.Empty)

                batch.Append(output)
                If i < reader.FieldCount - 1 Then
                    batch.Append("|")
                End If
            Next i

            batch.Append(vbCrLf)
            rowCount += 1

            If rowCount Mod batchSize = 0 Then
                Dim now = Date.Now
                Dim sinceLastSeconds = DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, lastReport, now)
                lastReport = now
                LogEvent($"INFO: Processing row {rowCount} {sinceLastSeconds}s since last")
                
                Dim fileWriteStart = Date.Now
                'LogEvent($"INFO: Starting Writing {rowCount} row(s) to file for {report.ReportName}. {sinceLastSeconds}s since last")
                WriteToFile(filename, batch.ToString(), True)

                Dim fileWriteSeconds = DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, fileWriteStart, Date.Now)
                LogEvent($"INFO: Finished Writing another {batchSize} row(s) to file in {fileWriteSeconds}s for {report.ReportName}")

                batch.Clear()

            End If
        End While

        'LogEvent($"INFO: Starting Writing {rowCount} row(s) to {filename} for {report.ReportName}")
        WriteToFile(filename, batch.ToString(), True)
        LogEvent($"INFO: Finished Writing last row(s) to {filename} for {report.ReportName}")

        End Sub
```

```
Public Shared Function GetDataReader(ByVal strSQL As String, ByVal strConnection As String) As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
        Dim cnn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(strConnection)
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(strSQL, cnn)

        cnn.Open()

        GetDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)

    End Function
```

When this Sub starts it writes a batch of rows to the text file in less than 1s

```
07/12/2021 16:41:03: INFO: Finished Writing another 20000 row(s) to file in 0s for TAG_ATTRIBUTES
07/12/2021 16:41:03: INFO: Processing row 100000 0s since last
```

Each batch is slightly slower than the one before and by 2.5 million rows this has slowed to ~9s per batch:

```
07/12/2021 16:51:47: INFO: Processing row 2560000 9s since last
07/12/2021 16:51:37: INFO: Finished Writing another 20000 row(s) to file in 0s for TAG_ATTRIBUTES
```

and by 15,000,000:

```
08/12/2021 05:23:07: INFO: Processing row 15000000 145s since last
08/12/2021 05:20:42: INFO: Finished Writing another 20000 row(s) to file in 0s for TAG_ATTRIBUTES
```

Process Memory usage in the app remains below 100MB throughout when monitored in the Visual Studio  Diagnostic tools.

[image]

This is .Net Framework 4. AnyCPU

I wonder what might be causing the gradual slow down?

I've investigated building the entire content of the output file in a StringBuilder. The same gradual slow down happens but memory usage is in the GBytes as the StringBuilder populates.

Comment: Have you profiled the code to see where the time is being spent?  Have you looked at the database wait statistics?  My wild guess would be that the time is being spent in `reader.read()` and that if you look at the query plan, you'd see a plan that potentially takes increasing amounts of time to fetch the next n rows (i.e. a full table scan on a table where lots of the initial rows match the predicates but fewer and fewer rows match as the scan gets to the end of the table so the database has to do increasing amounts of work for each batch).

Comment: Great suggestions by Justin. I'm no expert on profiling but what I've discovered is: 34.8% GenerateTextSqlReportWithCurrent,  31.1%  GetValue, 31.0% GetValueBinding, 30.8% OraOLEDB19.dll ... 30.6% OraOLEDBrmc19.dll – which I guess confirms that most of the time in the Sub is being spent with the read.

Comment: If only 34.8% of the time is being spent in `GenerateTextSqlReportWithCurrent`, where is the other 65.2% being spent?  I would have expected `GenerateTextSqlReportWithCurrent` to be 99.9% or so of the total time.  Presumably, all the other values are subsets of the 34.8% number.

Comment: I've performed another Snapshot.  With the Subsystems drop down on _All Subsystems_ The  `GenerateTextSqlReportWithCurrent`, part of System Code  is now 49.5%.  Within `GenerateTextSqlReportWithCurrent`,  the hierarchy is  GetValue(48.2%,) -> GetValueBinding (48.1%) -> GetRowDataFromHandle(48.1%) -> OraOLEDB19.dll (48%) -> OraOLEDBrst19.dll(47.9%) -> OraOLEDBrmc19.dll(47.9%)    



If I change the Subsystems dropdown to _System code_, then  `GenerateTextSqlReportWithCurrent` contributes 99.9% with OraOLEDBrmc19.dll at the bottom of the hierarchy contributing 96.9%

Comment: The Subsystems drop down in the Perforrmance Profiler shows 50.5% Native Code.  49.5% System Code, 3.7% Waiting for CPU, with User code, String, GC Wait, File I/O & Reflection all accounting for < 0.1%

Comment: Connections, commands and DataReaders all need to have their Dispose methods called so they can release their unmanaged resources. Holding a connection open while you do all that text manipulation (DataReaders require an open connection) to a terrible long time.

Answer (score 0):

To demonstrate what I said in comments. `Using` blocks close and dispose the objects.

```
Public Shared Function GetDataTable(ByVal strSQL As String, ByVal strConnection As String) As OleDb.OleDbDataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using cnn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(strConnection),
        cmd As New OleDbCommand(strSQL, cnn)
        cnn.Open()
        Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            dt.Load(reader)
        End Using
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function
```

The parts of `GenerateTextSqlReportWithCurrent` that would change.

```
    Dim ColumnNames As String() = From dc As DataColumn In dt.Columns
                                  Select dc.ColumnName
    Dim strNames = String.Join(", ", ColumnNames)
    WriteToFile(filename, strNames, False)

    Dim i As Integer
    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        For i = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
            Dim output As String
            output = Replace(row(i).ToString, vbCr, String.Empty)
            output = Replace(output, vbLf, String.Empty)
            output = Replace(output, "|", String.Empty)

            batch.Append(output)
            If i < dt.Columns.Count - 1 Then
                batch.Append("|")
            End If
        Next
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Implementing Mary's suggestion, as follows, requires that all the data from the query is loaded into memory (15 million DataRow objects).   After a few million DataRows were created the application slowed down and after 1 hour had only loaded 5 million rows with 3 GBytes of Process Memory in use.  The application was executing the dt.Load(reader) line.  So unfortunately this is not a practical when dealing with such large quantities of records.

I will go with a simple SSIS package to do this work.  I do not understand how, but it is able to export 15 million rows to a text file in around 10 mins in my environment.

```
Private Sub GenerateTextSqlReportWithCurrent(report As TblreportEntity, filename As String)

         Const batchSize = 20000

         Dim encryption As New ClassEncrypt
         LogEvent($"INFO:          Filling DataTable for report {report.ReportName}")
         Dim dt as DataTable = GetDataTable(report.Sql,IMOracle2.GetConnectString(My.Settings.DB_Instance, encryption.Decrypt(My.Settings.DB_UserID), encryption.Decrypt(My.Settings.DB_PWD)))
         LogEvent($"INFO: Finished Filling DataTable for report {report.ReportName}")

         Dim columnNames = From dc As DataColumn In dt.Columns
                 Select dc.ColumnName
         Dim strNames = String.Join("|", columnNames)

         WriteToFile(filename, strNames, False)
         
         Dim batch As New StringBuilder()

         Dim rowCount As Integer
         Dim i As Integer
         For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
             For i = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
                 Dim output As String
                 output = Replace(row(i).ToString, vbCr, String.Empty)
                 output = Replace(output, vbLf, String.Empty)
                 output = Replace(output, "|", String.Empty)

                 batch.Append(output)
                 If i < dt.Columns.Count - 1 Then
                     batch.Append("|")
                 End If
             Next i
             
             batch.Append(vbCrLf)
             rowCount += 1

             Dim lastReport As DateTime = DateTime.Now()

             If rowCount Mod batchSize = 0 Then
                 Dim now = Date.Now
                 Dim sinceLastSeconds = DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, lastReport, now)
                 lastReport = now
                 LogEvent($"INFO: Processing row {rowCount} {sinceLastSeconds}s since last")
                
                 Dim fileWriteStart = Date.Now
                 'LogEvent($"INFO: Starting Writing {rowCount} row(s) to file for {report.ReportName}. {sinceLastSeconds}s since last")
                 WriteToFile(filename, batch.ToString(), True)

                 Dim fileWriteSeconds = DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, fileWriteStart, Date.Now)
                 LogEvent($"INFO: Finished Writing another {batchSize} row(s) to file in {fileWriteSeconds}s for {report.ReportName}")

                 batch.Clear()

             End If

         Next row

        WriteToFile(filename, batch.ToString(), True)
        LogEvent($"INFO: Finished Writing last row(s) to {filename} for {report.ReportName}")

        End Sub
```